# Электронное расписание учебного заведения

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Кто знает как распределить по дням расписание?

Comment: Автоматически или в ручную?

Comment: Для автоматического - вам надо взять несколько десятков тысяч рублей и гугл...

Comment: Вот, вот..... поэтому мне для начало в ручную. 
Исходники я не жду. Мне идея реализации нужна.

Comment: Распределить ( select ), Проверить на пересечения ( 1 препод в 1 время, 1 класс в 1 время, 1 аудитория в 1 время ), проверить на занятость ( нет окон )

Comment: Это проверка... А мне распределение по дням.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаешь лог расписания, там указываешь день недели, номер урока по порядку, название предмета, его аудиторию. Это в случае если расписание статично. Затем, чтобы вытащить данные, составляешь `SQL` запрос для каждого дня отдельно, вставляешь это дело в двумерный массив(`Predmet[day_of_week][num_of_less]`), значения в котором будут предметы. То же самое для аудитории и др. И в конце выводишь массив в таблицу.

Comment: Идея понятна, то что надо.
Спасибо за внимание